# Using the OpenSocial API for commercial products

Tags: facebook, twitter, opensocial

i would like to know if i can develop a OpenSocial based application for Orkut, Facebook, twitter with commercial purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can definitely do that!